# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

I have no clue where to start. I thought maybe U substitute for $(1+x^2)$ then integration by parts but that gets messy fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
Substituting $y=\arctan x$ gives
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{y\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}\,dy=\int_0^{\pi/2}y\sin y\cos y\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}y\sin2y\,dy$$
Integration by parts should follow from here.

Comment: I did't even think of that I'll try it out thanks

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan x ~ d\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$